# How to read bookmark links of pdf file?

Tags: java, itext, bookmarks

I am reading pdf file in java code using `PdfReader` class.
I want to read the bookmarks index/chapter links shown in red colored box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(PdfReader)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/SimpleBookmark.html#getBookmark%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader%29).